# AzDO YAML pipeline publish Html test result

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines

Azure DevOps still doesn't have a built in way to publish test html reports to the pipeline. [This request](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/idea/491426/support-for-generic-html-publishing-inside-build-a.html) is over a year old now and still no announcement on it being on the roadmap.

[This article](https://medium.com/@tsuyoshiushio/azure-devops-yaml-pipeline-with-net-core-and-coverage-report-b84b5b282a95) suggests it is possible by naming the file index.html. However, I'm not seeing how the file is published - can anyone help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sorry, for now we do not have any build-in feature to directly publish html file and have  the ability to view the HTML report inline as a web page on Azure pipelines.

> **Azure DevOps Coverage page show index.html on the web**. However, the
>   CSS and Javascript should be included. For this purpose we can use
>   HTMLInline to include CSS and Javascript on the index.html.

The article you are referring, seems related to code coverage not test page. There is a code coverage tab next to Tests tab.

[image]

According to the description, the workaround seems to modify the original index.html file of Code Coverage and display something on it. If so, there is no need to publish, Azure DevOps will find the index.html and auto display info of it.

That's not a common way to publish html report. Suggest you use `Publish Pipeline Artifact` task to publish generated html reports and then download to view them locally.

Or you could also give a try with 3rd-party extension-- [Publish HTML](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=Farrellsoft.publish-html-task&ssr=false#overview)

Comment: Thanks @PatrickLu-MSFT,  publishing the report as an artifact is indeed what I'm doing for now. Will give the extension a go until such time it's a native feature.